# How to use generics when working with different objects having same properties

Tags: java

I'm learning core Java and this is my first question. I'm learning *Generics* from YouTube. I have 2 classes, *Book* and *PostCard*. Both have 3 properties *title*, *price* and *author*. In **getData** method I'm using generic type. Here is my code:

```
class Book {
    public String title;
    public  int price;
    public String author;

    Book(String book_title, int book_price, String book_author) {
        this.title=book_title;
        this.price=book_price;
        this.author=book_author;
    }
}

class PostCard {
    public String title;
    public  int price;
    public String author;

    PostCard(String card_title, int card_price, String card_author) {
        this.title=card_title;
        this.price=card_price;
        this.author=card_author;
    }
}

public class GenericsExample {

    public <E> void getData(E anything) {
        System.out.println("Name: " +anything.title); // ERROR
        System.out.println("Price: " + anything.price); // ERROR
        System.out.println("Author: " + anything.author); // ERROR
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Book book[] = new Book[5];
        book[0]= new Book("Let us C",270,"Yashwant Kanetkar");

        PostCard card[] = new PostCard[5];
        card[0]= new PostCard("Happy new year!",50,"Tanzeel Mirza");

        GenericsExample ge = new GenericsExample();
        ge.getData(card[0]);
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable title
  location: variable anything of type E
```

I'm using JDK 16.
Please point out my mistake. Why I'm getting this error.

Comment: You have two options : 1. Use an interface that both `postcard` and `book` inherit from. 2. Use reflection api

Comment: Sure sir, but whats wrong with this approach

Comment: Your generic E doesn't have those ivars. That's not what a generic is. Generics are more intended for cases where the input type doesn't matter (like how a List can accept any type because the List constructor is parameterizable with a generic `List<E>`). It seems more like you are intending Book and Postcard to inherit from a single superclass with those 3 ivars.

Comment: @David, that means my whole understanding about generics is incorrect :-(

Comment: It might be. Granted you can make a generic extend from another class, so you could finagle this to work, but it's probably not really what you want. Just from looking at your code I would make a class that holds your 3 ivars and make both Book and Postcard extend it and drop the generic completely.

Comment: As @MMD suggested. I'm right now creating an interface.

Comment: Generics are mostly useful for collections, where the collection doesn't use the methods or state of the objects it is storing -- except methods available on Object such as equals() -- it only stores it. There are some edge cases where generics are also useful, but mostly it's collections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for error is that the compiler doesn't know that the generic type E has 'title' and other attributes. Change your code like so:

Add a parent class to Book, Product (Since you are using attributes directly, you will have to create a parent class. Ideally, you should be using methods and implement an interface instead):

```
class Product {
    public String title;
    public  int price;
    public String author;
}

class Book extends Product {...}

class PostCard extends Product {...}

public class GenericsExample {

    public <E extends Product> void getData(E anything) {...}
}
```

Comment: Tried your solution first. I'm getting this: 

`Name: null
Price: 0
Author: null`

Comment: You need to assign values to the attributes if you want them to not be null or 0. The answer was for your original question on why you are seeing ERROR in the println lines, which are compiler errors.

Comment: let me go through other answer here. I'll come back to you. i really appreciate your help

Comment: The issue you are having is that you cannot override attributes. Remove them from the child classes and have them only in the parent as in my code snippet.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to specify the existence of the generics in your class and then use them as if they were types (or in the method as well, but you will need to specify what it extends):

```
public class GenericsExample<E extends YourClass> {

    public void getData(E anything) {
        System.out.println("Name: " +anything.title); // ERROR
        System.out.println("Price: " + anything.price); // ERROR
        System.out.println("Author: " + anything.author); // ERROR
    }
//...

}
```

Where `YourClass` is a `class` that has `title`,  `price` and `author` data members. Instantiate it as

```
GenericsExample<PostCard> ge = new GenericsExample<PostCard>();
```

Note that `PostCard` needs to extend `YourClass`

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

```
public<E> void getData(E anything) {
    System.out.println("Name: " +anything.title); 
    System.out.println("Price: " + anything.price);
    System.out.println("Author: " + anything.author);
}
```

You expect to print the title, etc because you called getData with an instance of PostCard.

The generics allows that.  But you can call getData with an instance of **anything** and you won't get a compiler error at the calling statement.  But why would you expect an instance of Animal to have a `title, price, and author` if you called `getData` with an instance of the Animal class.

You can fix the above by doing the following:

```
public<E extends PostCard> void getData(E anything) {
    System.out.println("Name: " +anything.title);
    System.out.println("Price: " + anything.price);
    System.out.println("Author: " + anything.author);
}
```

But that does constrain the method to only work with anything that subclasses postcard.

Just remember that one of generics' primary functions (if not the main one) is to enforce proper typing at compile time rather than runtime. This will help to avoid cast class errors that one would have had to do prior to generics.  And during the compilation process all the generics stuff is erased.

BTW, `getData` as a name for a method that can't return anything doesn't really make much sense.

If you want your entire example to work, implement an `Interface.` or an `abstract class`

```
interface Info {
    public String getTitle();
    
    public int getPrice();
    
    public String getAuthor();
}

class Book1 implements Info {
    public String title;
    public int price;
    public String author;
    
    Book1(String book_title, int book_price, String book_author) {
        this.title = book_title;
        this.price = book_price;
        this.author = book_author;
    }
    
    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    
    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }
}

class PostCard implements Info {
    public String title;
    public int price;
    public String author;
    
    PostCard(String card_title, int card_price, String card_author) {
        this.title = card_title;
        this.price = card_price;
        this.author = card_author;
    }
    
    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    
    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }
    
}

public class GenericsExample {
    
    public <E extends Info> void getData(E anything) {
        System.out.println("Name: " + anything.getTitle()); // ERROR
        System.out.println("Price: " + anything.getPrice()); // ERROR
        System.out.println("Author: " + anything.getAuthor()); // ERROR
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Book1 book[] = new Book1[5];
        book[0] = new Book1("Let us C", 270, "Yashwant Kanetkar");
        
        PostCard card[] = new PostCard[5];
        card[0] =
                new PostCard("Happy new year!", 50, "Tanzeel Mirza");
        
        GenericsExample ge = new GenericsExample();
        ge.getData(book[0]);
        ge.getData(card[0]);
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Name: Let us C
Price: 270
Author: Yashwant Kanetkar
Name: Happy new year!
Price: 50
Author: Tanzeel Mirza
```